# Gradle build time so slow with Google Play Services

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

My current build time is about 28-30 second.

But when I add `Google Play Services Mobile Ads` library, it's increasing to 50-60 seconds. Why this library is taking to much time build? I also applied all "reduce build time" settings but nothing helped.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.1.0'
```

Comment: Try turn on "Offline work" for Gradle in Android Studio settings.

Comment: If it takes 30 seconds, I don't think it's really big problem here. But, try to switch maven to "offline work", close other unused apps, or add other libs to test (compare with GP Service lib)...

Comment: It's normally 30 seconds, but with necessary lib, it's switching to 60 seconds. I am also using "-offline" option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue with same library but after a few tweaks, my build time reduced 70 seconds to 45 seconds.

Here is my current compiler settings, it may help:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Including the play-services library does slow down the build time. You can use the latest android studio, which supports intant run. It's a feature that allows to push the changes in the running app. The activity restarts in a few seconds and you can see the new changes in effect.

You can find more about it [here at the official documentation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/instant-run).

It classifies the changes we make in our code to three parts: hot swap, warm swap and cold swap, based on how much load would the change would put on the build. Hotter the swap - quicker the build. Some loady changes like - changes in the manifest file, structural code changes, resource-changes come into the cold swap. Therefore in those cases, build will take the time it used to take.

But, it definitely is a cure to all the wait-time that we had to suffer just for changing a small insignificant line of code.